# Set specific properties for data in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let us say I want to make a ADT as follows in Haskell:

```
data Properties = Property String [String]
  deriving (Show,Eq)
```

I want to know if it is possible to give the second list a bounded and enumerated property? Basically the first element of the list will be the `minBound` and the last element will be the `maxBound`. I am trying,

```
data Properties a = Property String [a]
  deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Bounded (Properties a) where
  minBound a = head a
  maxBound a  = (head . reverse) a
```

But not having much luck.

Comment: You can do it. You just can't call your functions `minBound` and `maxBound`, because those values only get the *type* as "input", not a value of that type.

Comment: So I can't define a bounded instance of `Properties` but must give it that functionality in some other way?

Comment: Also, as an aside: unless you actually plan on installing new properties with new sets of values *at runtime*, I strongly recommend considering using the built-in records and simple enumerated types. I would guess you are asking about this because you are thinking about using a common idiom in dynamically typed languages like Python and Ruby where you have a dictionary with values whose types depend on which key you're looking at. This is much more naturally translated to a record in Haskell than to a (dynamically typed!) dictionary.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what `Bounded` says about a type. It signifies that you wish to define a lower limit and an upper limit. `minBound` and `maxBound` must have type `Bounded a => a`. Note that these signify concrete values. You can't use a function to define those values without dependent types.

Comment: @Daniel, you made a good guess. Actually my purpose _is_ to define new values _at_ runtime. In-fact what I want eventually to do is, let the user define properties through statements via the prompt like `"DefStmt prop "Pets" ["Dogs", "Cats", "Birds"] which I will parse and (hope to) associate to my ADT.

Comment: Also, the result of `minBound` has to have the type `Properties a`, but you seem to want it to produce a `String`. These are not the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well no, you can't do quite what you're asking, but maybe you'll find inspiration in this other neat trick.

```
{-# language ScopedTypeVariables, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Data.Reflection -- from the reflection package
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty (..))
import Data.Proxy

-- Just the plain string part
newtype Pstring p = P String deriving Eq

-- Those properties you're interested in. It will
-- only be possible to produce bounds if there's at
-- least one property, so NonEmpty makes more sense
-- than [].
type Props = NonEmpty String

-- This is just to make a Show instance that does
-- what you seem to want easier to write. It's not really
-- necessary.
data Properties = Property String [String] deriving Show
```

Now we get to the key part, where we use reflection to produce class instances that can depend on run-time values. Roughly speaking, you can think of

```
Reifies x t => ...
```

as being a class-level version of

```
\(x :: t) -> ...
```

Because it operates at the class level, you can use it to parametrize instances. Since `Reifies x t` binds a *type variable* `x`, rather than a *term variable*, you need to use `reflect` to actually get the value back. If you happen to have a value on hand whose type ends in `p`, then you can just apply `reflect` to that value. Otherwise, you can always magic up a `Proxy :: Proxy p` to do the job.

```
-- If some Props are "in the air" tied to the type p,
-- then we can show them along with the string.
instance Reifies p Props => Show (Pstring p) where
  showsPrec k p@(P str) =
     showsPrec k $ Property str (NE.toList $ reflect p)

-- If some Props are "in the air" tied to the type p,
-- then we can give Pstring p a Bounded instance.
instance Reifies p Props => Bounded (Pstring p) where
  minBound = P $ NE.head (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy p))
  maxBound = P $ NE.last (reflect (Proxy :: Proxy p))
```

Now we need to have a way to actually bind types that can be passed to the type-level lambdas. This is done using the `reify` function. So let's throw some `Prop`s into the air and then let the butterfly nets get them back.

```
main :: IO ()
main = reify ("Hi" :| ["how", "are", "you"]) $
  \(_ :: Proxy p) -> do
    print (minBound :: Pstring p)
    print (maxBound :: Pstring p)

./dfeuer@squirrel:~/src> ./WeirdBounded 
Property "Hi" ["Hi","how","are","you"]
Property "you" ["Hi","how","are","you"]
```

You can think of `reify x $ \(p :: Proxy p) -> ...` as binding a type `p` to the value `x`; you can then pass the type `p` where you like by constraining things to have types involving `p`.

---

If you're just doing a couple of things, all this machinery is way more than necessary. Where it gets nice is when you're performing lots of operations with values that have phantom types carrying extra information. In many cases, you can avoid most of the explicit applications of `reflect` and the explicit proxy handling, because type inference just takes care of it all for you. For a good example of this technique in action, see the [`hyperloglog`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hyperloglog) package. Configuration information for the `HyperLogLog` data structure is carried in a type parameter; this guarantees, at compile time, that only similarly configured structures are merged with each other.